# How to feed Solr index into Mahout for classification?

Tags: solr, machine-learning, classification, mahout

I have a Solr index and I want to feed some of that index fields into Mahout's classifier. They say  in "Mahout in Action" book:

> Approaches to encoding classifiable data as a vector
>   Approach: Use one Vector cell per word, category, or continuous value
>   Use Case: When dumping a Lucene index as Vectors for clustering

Thats it. Good luck finding a way to use that. Not in the book and not on the internet (unless Google is really hiding that from me).

Any ideas how to feed Solr index into Mahout for classification? I'm interested to do it via Mahout API, not the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene has classification too : http://soleami.com/blog/comparing-document-classification-functions-of-lucene-and-mahout.html

Comment: How that answer my question?